# XTK build error Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xtk

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, tried both 32 and 64 bit versions

This is what i got when i tried to build xtk. Please help how to solve the issue

```
george@laptop-4:~/X4/utils$ ./build.py -b -t -e
*-----------------------*
Compiling Code
 /home/george/X4/lib/closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Scanning paths... 
 /home/george/X4/lib/closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: 936 sources scanned. 
 /home/george/X4/lib/closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Building dependency tree.. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/george/X4/lib/closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 256, in 
main()
File "/home/george/X4/lib/closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 241, in main
options.compiler_flags)
File "/home/george/X4/lib/closure-library/closure/bin/build/jscompiler.py", line 50, in Compile
if not (distutils.version.LooseVersion(_GetJavaVersion()) >=
File "/home/george/X4/lib/closure-library/closure/bin/build/jscompiler.py", line 31, in _GetJavaVersion
proc = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>> OUTPUT: xtk.js
Code compiled
*-----------------------*
*-----------------------*
Testing code

======== GOOGLE CHROME RESULTS ========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build.py", line 177, in 
    scripts.test.calculate( paths.xtkDir + '/testing/xtk_tests_build.html', paths.xtkLibDir )
  File "/home/george/X4/utils/scripts/test.py", line 60, in calculate
    display = Display( visible=0, size=( 1024, 768 ) )
  File "/home/george/X4/lib/PyVirtualDisplay/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 33, in __init__
    self._obj = self.display_class( 
  File "/home/george/X4/lib/PyVirtualDisplay/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 51, in display_class
    cls.check_installed()
  File "/home/george/X4/lib/PyVirtualDisplay/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py", line 33, in check_installed
    EasyProcess([PROGRAM, '-help'], url=URL, ubuntu_package=PACKAGE).check_installed()
  File "/home/george/X4/lib/EasyProcess/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 201, in check_installed
    raise EasyProcessCheckInstalledError(self)
easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']
OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory  
Program install error! 
You can install it in terminal:
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?  What does it say?  Did you try to do what it suggests?

Comment: I have read the error message but not sure how to deal with the issue. I haven't editted any of the files got from xtk. But just tried to build. Not sure how to deal this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tested under my Ubuntu and has the samed error and solved it (btw compilation succeeded but I didn't try the lib after)

Look at the end of the error :

```
easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']
OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory  
Program install error! 
You can install it in terminal:
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

They say that "xvfb" is missing, so I installed it with "sudo apt-get install xvfb" and then it compiled. Does it works for you ?

However after compilation the testing outs errors :

```
*-----------------------*
Testing code

======== GOOGLE CHROME RESULTS ========
RUNNING OFFSCREEN TESTING..
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./build.py", line 177, in <module>
scripts.test.calculate( paths.xtkDir + '/testing/xtk_tests_build.html', paths.xtkLibDir )
File "/home/fabien/X_3DNeo/utils/scripts/test.py", line 62, in calculate
chrome_results = runTests( xtkTestFile, xtkLibDir, browserString )
File "/home/fabien/X_3DNeo/utils/scripts/test.py", line 151, in runTests
result = browser.execute_script( 'return window.G_testRunner.getReport(true);' )
File "/home/fabien/X_3DNeo/lib/selenium/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 385, in execute_script
{'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
File "/home/fabien/X_3DNeo/lib/selenium/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 153, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/fabien/X_3DNeo/lib/selenium/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 147, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u"Script execution failed. Script: return window.G_testRunner.getReport(true);;\n Cannot call method 'getReport' of undefined"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ricola3D for the hints. I installed the "xvfb" and "Java" and it build like a breeze.